# Avoiding rerendering of my custom items in a Flat List

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I created a custom item for my Flat List which shows the name and the image ( retrieved by his url) of a certain product. The user can filter this products by their names, and the new filtered data is passed again to the Flat List. The problem is that whenever I filter the data, Flat List re-renders every custom item, so the Image components inside  have  to download the pic again, causing a flickering effect. This is an approximate example of what I mean:

```
function test(){

    initialData=[
        {
            text: 'product A',
            image: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300',
            id: 1 
        }, 
        {
            text: 'product B',
            image: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300',
            id: 2
        }, 
        {
            text: 'product C',
            image: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300',
            id: 3
        }, 
    ]

    const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(initialData);

    const handlePress = () =>(
        
        setFilteredData(filterData(data)); // Filter data by some parameters
        
    )

    const renderItem = (props) => {
        return(
            <View>
                <Image>{props.text}</Image>
                <Text source={{uri: props.image}}></Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

    return(
        <>
            <Button onPress={() => handlePress()}></Button>
            <FlatList  
                data={data}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                renderItem={renderItem}
            />
        </>

    )
}
```

Comment: Hmm, browser should cache them by default after downloads them for the first time, it should not be your code responsibility to think about that. Maybe you were debugging with opened developer tools, along with checked `Disable cache` options in network tab?

Comment: Add `key` property in  renderItem function for root <View> component something like this `<View key={props.id}>` it won't re-render..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first must to say in order to avoiding unnecessary rendering data you are be able to use **useMemo** and **useCallback** methods (in functional programming) for memorizing your variables and your functions (check hooks [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) documents). some procedures can help you for improving your code:

1. Don't put the static data inside your function, for example put **initialData** outside of your **test** function or memorize it by useMemo.
2. Don't use inline function inside components and as far as possible memorize them.
3. You can create independent component for your FlatList item and memorize it by **memo** then use them or memorize renderItem inside your test function.
4. For use image in your app (specifically when you have large numbers of image) use [react-native-fast-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image) that help you avoiding to re-rendering images by caching them.